# Making a Collapsible Sticky Header — With React

Tags: reactjs, header, sticky

I wish you a good day.

I want to adapt the header behavior in Medium.com, savee.it, Instagram tabbar to my own site.

[Faraz Khan example on medium](https://medium.com/citymall-tech/making-a-collapsible-sticky-header-animations-with-react-native-6ad7763875c3)

I would like to ask for an example made with react native in the link. and below is sample code from Savee.it.

I want to do this with next js, can anyone explain how it works?

```js
import type SVNav from '@apps/www/src/www/components/SVNav';
import { getWindowScrollTop } from '@pkgs/shared-client/helpers/dom';
import { unit } from '@pkgs/shared-client/styles/mixins';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import documentReady from 'document-ready';
import prefixAll from 'inline-style-prefixer/static';
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';
import setStyles from 'set-styles';
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge';

const POSITIONS = {
    TOP: 'top',
    BOTTOM: 'bottom',
} as const;

const _DefaultTopSpacer = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} className="h-0" {...props} />
));

const defaultProps: {
    position: ValueOf<typeof POSITIONS>;
    TopSpacerComponent: typeof _DefaultTopSpacer | typeof SVNav.TopSpacer;
} = {
    position: POSITIONS.TOP,
    TopSpacerComponent: _DefaultTopSpacer,
};

type Props = Partial<typeof defaultProps> & {
    className?: string;
    render: (state: State) => JSX.Element;
};

type State = {
    isHidden: boolean;
    isAtTop: boolean;
};

class SVStickyBar extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    static POSITIONS = POSITIONS;

    static defaultProps = defaultProps;

    elementRef = React.createRef<HTMLElement>();
    spacerRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();

    y = 0;
    top = 0;
    height = 0;

    state: State = {
        isHidden: false,
        isAtTop: true,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.resize();

        documentReady(this.resize);
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.update);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize);
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.update);
    }

    resize = () => {
        const element = this.elementRef.current;

        if (!element) {
            setTimeout(this.resize, 100);

            return;
        }

        const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

        this.height = parseInt(computedStyle.height) + parseInt(computedStyle.paddingBottom);

        const spacer = this.spacerRef.current;

        if (spacer) {
            // spacer.style.height = unit(parseInt(computedStyle.height) + 16);
            spacer.style.height = unit(parseInt(computedStyle.height));
        }

        this.update();
    };

    update = () => {
        const { isHidden, isAtTop } = this.state;

        const isBottom = this.props.position === POSITIONS.BOTTOM;

        const scrollY = Math.max(0, getWindowScrollTop());
        const min = Math.min(this.y, scrollY);

        const t = Math.min(0, Math.max(this.height * -1, min - scrollY));
        this.y = scrollY + t;

        if (this.top != t) {
            this.top = t;

            if (this.elementRef.current) {
                setStyles(
                    this.elementRef.current,
                    prefixAll({
                        transform: `translateY(${t * (isBottom ? -1 : 1)}px)`,
                    }),
                );
            }

            if (t <= this.height * -1) {
                if (!isHidden) {
                    this.setState({
                        isHidden: true,
                    });
                }
            } else if (isHidden) {
                this.setState({
                    isHidden: false,
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.y <= 0 || scrollY <= this.height) {
            if (!isAtTop) {
                this.setState({
                    isAtTop: true,
                });
            }
        } else if (isAtTop) {
            this.setState({
                isAtTop: false,
            });
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { render, className, TopSpacerComponent, position, ...otherProps } = this.props; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
        const { isHidden } = this.state;

        return (
            <>
                {position === POSITIONS.TOP && TopSpacerComponent && (
                    <TopSpacerComponent ref={this.spacerRef} />
                )}
                <div
                    ref={this.elementRef as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}
                    className={twMerge(
                        clsx(
                            'prevent-grid-select fixed top-0 left-0 right-0',
                            isHidden && 'pointer-events-none',
                            position === POSITIONS.TOP && 'z-index-nav',
                            position === POSITIONS.BOTTOM && 'z-index-nav-small bottom-0 top-auto',
                        ),
                        className,
                    )}
                    {...otherProps}
                >
                    {render(this.state)}
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default SVStickyBar;
```

I want to hide the title when going down and show that the given value decreases to zero when going up.

**The code below is working smoothly now.**

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  isHidden: boolean;
  isAtTop: boolean;
  align?: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
  className?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const positions = {
  top: 'top',
  bottom: 'bottom'
}

const defaultProps = {
  position: positions.top
}


function Toolbar({ className, children }: Props) {
  const elementRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const [say, setSay] = useState(0)

  let y = 0;
  let top = 0;
  let height = 48;

  let isHidden: false;
  let isAtTop: true;

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const isBottom = defaultProps.position === positions.bottom;
      const scrollY = Math.max(0, window.scrollY);
      const min = Math.min(y, scrollY);

      const t = Math.min(0, Math.max(height * -1, min - scrollY));
      y = scrollY + t;

      if (top != t) {
        top = t
        if (elementRef.current) {
          elementRef.current.style.transform = `translateY(${t * (isBottom ? -1 : 1)}px)`;
        }
        if (t <= height * -1) {
          if (!isHidden) {
            isHidden: true;
          } else if (isHidden) {
            isHidden: false;
          }
        }
      }
      if (y <= 0 || scrollY <= height) {
        if (!isAtTop) {
          isAtTop: true;
        }
      } else if (isAtTop) {
        isAtTop: false;
      }
    };

    // Scroll olaylarını dinleme
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    // Temizlik fonksiyonu
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [elementRef]);

  return (
    <header ref={elementRef}
      id="__toolbar"
      className={`
        fixed
        top-0
        w-full
        bg-white
        dark:bg-black
        z-50
        ${className}
      `}
    >
      <div className="
        w-full
        mx-auto
        px-4
        flex
        justify-stretch
        h-12
      ">
        {children}
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```